# How to limit number of rows displayed in a rdlc report table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, rdlc

In my rdlc report, I used Report Item Table only. When I generate report there has so many rows. How to define the row counts for page? I mean I want to show 10 rows in one page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a parent group to your current rowset and set its group expression to =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/10. In the Group Properties you then check the Page Breaks option to "Between groups", (and toggle the visibility).
Maybe this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328%28SQL.90%29.aspx) link could be a starting point for you.